# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError - Unable to load library - Can't obtain InputStream

Tags: java, linux

I'm trying to install a Java package in linux, Jeigen, and I run into an error when testing the installation using

```
java -cp build/linux-64/Jeigen-linux-64.jar:build/linux-64/jna-4.1.0.jar jeigen.TestSimple
```

The error:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'jeigen-linux-64': Can't obtain InputStream for linux-x86-64/libjeigen-linux-64.so
            at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(NativeLibrary.java:271)
            at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getInstance(NativeLibrary.java:398)
            at com.sun.jna.Native.register(Native.java:1396)
            at com.sun.jna.Native.register(Native.java:1156)
            at jeigen.JeigenJna$Jeigen.<clinit>(JeigenJna.java:64)
            at jeigen.DenseMatrix.mmul(DenseMatrix.java:1049)
            at jeigen.TestSimple.main(TestSimple.java:14)
```

I obtained two jar files, Jeigen-linux-64.jar and jna-4.1.0.jar (which i've exported to my classpath), and the libjeigen-linux-64.so lib  was built in my home path /home/.jeigen/native/libjeigen-linux-64.so

Any ideas on what is going on?

Comment: Usually such libraries must be accessible from the PATH environemnet variable (or at least, this a way to go).

Answer (score 0):

[Here is the source for NativeLibrary](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/master/src/com/sun/jna/NativeLibrary.java) - the line numbers don't quite line up with your stack trace so this isn't the source to the version you have, but close enough. As you can see, it's looking in many, many, many places, and it logs via `java.util.logging`, so you can use  something like:

Put this in a file:

```
# Logging
handlers = java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
# Console Logging
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = ALL
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter =  java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter 
java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format = %1$tY-%1$tm-%1$td %1$tH:%1$tM:%1$tS %4$s %2$s %5$s%6$s%n
```

Start java with `java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/path/to/thatfile`.

That'll help a lot.

The answer is probably that you need to futz with `-Djna.library.path=/path/where/your/solibfileis` or to move your solib file around to a better place - by letting JNA log what it is trying to do, the paths where you need to put this stuff and the options on how to specify where to look will become clear.